# Can you run Chi-Square test for 4x4?

Tags: chi-squared-test

Im a bit confused about when you can run Chi-square test of Independence. I know you can run it for 2x2 and 3x3 tables but what about 4x4? or 2x3 or 4x2 etc??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run a chi-squared test for independence or homogeneity for any number of levels in both variables.

Just keep in mind that the test becomes inaccurate when expected count for some cells gets too small (usually said 5). Therefore, when the number of cells is increased, sample size may need be increased, too.